# JavaScript to get value from HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to extract the text from a multi-row, multi-column html table. A column from the table is defined below. All the id values are dynamic so I'll need to reference other attributes or tags to fetch it. The value I'm trying to fetch here is "PERS". It is the only cell containing text.

```HTML
<table id="tableview-1033-record-2154" data-boundview="tableview-1033" data-recordid="2154" data-recordindex="0"
    class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="  x-grid-row">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-ResourceType-0 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable vux-grid-cell-selected"
                style="width:96px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-ResourceType-0"
                id="ext-element-1962">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="" id="ext-element-1841"><span
                        class="vux-glyph-font-icon vux-font-icon-grey vux-font-icon-xx-small vux-grid-field-menu-icon vux-font-icon-hidden"
                        colindex="0" rowindex="0" id="ext-element-1996">&nbsp;</span>PERS</div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-ResourceCode-0 x-unselectable grid-cell-error-input"
                style="width:96px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-ResourceCode-0"
                id="ext-element-1838">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="" id="ext-element-1842"><span
                        class="vux-glyph-font-icon vux-font-icon-grey vux-font-icon-xx-small vux-grid-field-menu-icon vux-font-icon-hidden"
                        colindex="1" rowindex="0" id="ext-element-1971">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-StaffRequired-0 x-unselectable grid-cell-error-input"
                style="width:204px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-StaffRequired-0"
                id="ext-element-1839">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;" id="ext-element-1843"><span
                        class="vux-glyph-font-icon vux-font-icon-grey vux-font-icon-xx-small vux-grid-field-menu-icon vux-font-icon-hidden"
                        colindex="2" rowindex="0" id="ext-element-1969">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
```

I was expecting this to work but no such luck ...

```js
  var input1rw = document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-TIMM103-Block-2-colstate-ResourceCode-0 grid-cell-error-input x-unselectable');
  var input1cl = input1rw[0];
  console.log('result: ', input1cl.innerText);
```

After several hours of failure, I'd greatly appreciate some help from the experts.

Comment: The HTML example is incomplete so may behave unexpectedly but for a single result something like `document.querySelector(".x-grid-cell-inner").textContent.trim()` will work within the scope of the current example

Comment: What exactly would be the relevant information to select the cell? Because if you know the row and column, it's pretty simple: https://jsfiddle.net/7vchg2L1/

Comment: Thanks Brian & Chris. I added more of the html to the post. I experimented with both your suggestions but am getting nothing returned. The table is multiple rows but each row has it's own table id. It is really ten one-row tables. Ultimately I will need to write to several of the cells in just the first row/table.

Comment: Chris - The example you provided was the key! I just had to tweak the indexes and use a non-id attribute for the querySelector argument. Huge thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get by class name as you were attempting however classes are intended to be applied to multiple elements so it returns a node list. You would want to select the node number for the element you wish to get. For example, the first element would be the following:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-cell-inner');
var single = elements[0].textContent.trim();
alert('the value is:' + single);
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I tried what you posted here, which is pretty similar to what I was trying to do. I get no errors but also get no value returned.

Comment: @puckhead using your example it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/anthonysbird/es2q5n8b/3/#&togetherjs=cIveMGqkP7

Comment: You are right Anthony. Answer accepted. I eventually had to identify the specific table by index. I added what I used as another answer. Now I just need to figure out how to write to that cell and get the value to stick.

Comment: Congrats on getting it solved @puckhead - to update try something like elements[0].innerHTML = '<span>hello</span>';

Answer (score 0):

Because the IDs were dynamic but the table would always be in the same place, I used the following to get the value:

```HTML
var tblID = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[15].id;
var tr = document.querySelector('#' + tblID).querySelectorAll('tr')[0];
var div = tr.querySelectorAll('td')[0].querySelector('div').childNodes[1].textContent;
console.log(div);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function GetCellValues() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) 
        {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said they cannot rely on ID since it is dynamic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).